# interpreting different distributions

Tags: distributions

How to interpret the result if the distribution of a dataset is different from the distribution of a subset of the dataset?

For example, the height of people in a dataset is normally distributed but the height of people in the subset of that dataset is uniformly distributed.

Comment: This is somewhat confused. Population distribution and sampling distribution are different concepts, and there is no reason to expect them to be equal! Samplig distribution of *what*? The mean, the median, the maximum of a sample of size 1, 10, 100 will be different ... Can you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for your comment.  I edit the question.  Hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on the particular case. For your particular example, you can say "the subset is weird!"

More generally, I would suggest comparing one subset to another. There is extensive literature on this, both here on CrossValidated and elsewhere.